# variable/string to a function

Tags: javascript, html

I'm at very beggining stage and I'd like to know something.. Is there a way to set a variable like this (or a similiar way)?

```
<body>

<button id="button1" onclick="change(this.something);"> click me </button>
<button id="button2" onclick="change(this.lorem);"> or this one </button>
<div id="target"> change this content </div>

<script>
function change(variable)
{
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = variable;
}
</script>
</body>
```

or something like this

```
<body>

<button id="button1" onclick="change(this.value(v1));"> click me </button>
<button id="button2" onclick="change(this.value(v2));"> or this one</button>

<div id="target"> change this content </div>

<script>
function change(value)
{
var v1 = "something";
var v2 = "lorem";

document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = variable;
}
</script>
```

of course both are not working.. just don't know how to find an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you mean to pass a string literal to the function, i.e. `change('literal text')`:

```js
function change(variable) {
  document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = variable;
}
```

```html
<button id="button1" onclick="change('something');"> click me </button>
<button id="button2" onclick="change('lorem');"> or this one </button>
<div id="target"> change this content </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you intent to set the contents of the div to `something` or `lorem`, then you should pass those using a string literal instead of trying to access a property on this.

```
<button id="button1" onclick="change('something');"> click me </button>
<button id="button2" onclick="change('lorem');"> or this one </button>
```

Using a string literal passes a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String) containing the value specified to the `change` function whereas using `this.something` is a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) which will try to get the value of the `something` property on the `this` object.

In your second example, you can't use `v1` and `v2` from the `onclick` handler because those variables are scoped inside your `change` function and aren't accessible from the outside.